# Geometry Transformations/Isometry

Tags: geometry

I need to prove that the transformation of $$(x,y)=(0.6x-0.8y, 0.8x+0.6y)$$ is an isometry.

I know that means proving the distance is the same but I don't know how to find the rotation point to figure the length of $(x,y)$ to that point and then the transformation point to the rotation point.

Comment: You need to show that the distance between two arbitrary points is unchanged by the transformation. This doesn’t really have anything to do with finding the distance of a point from the center of rotation.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

You can write it like

$$f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
0.6 & -0.8\\
0.8 & 0.6
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}$$

Can you see that it is a rotation?

So, you have to prove that $$|f(x_0,y_0)-f(x_1,y_1)|=|(x_0,y_0)-(x_1,y_1)|=|(x_0-x_1,y_0-y_1)|$$

but

$$|f(x_0,y_0)-f(x_1,y_1)|=\left|\begin{pmatrix}
0.6 & -0.8\\
0.8 & 0.6
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_0-x_1\\
y_0-y_1
\end{pmatrix}\right|$$

Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

You can search for fixed points by solving the system $(x,y)=f(x,y)$

$\begin{cases} x = 0.6x-0.8y \\ y = 0.8x+0.6y \end{cases}\iff
\begin{cases} 0.4x=-0.8y \\ 0.4y=0.8x \end{cases}\iff
\begin{cases} x=-2y \\ y=2x \end{cases}\iff
\begin{cases} x=0 \\ y=0 \end{cases}$

So $O=(0,0)$ is the only fixed point.

Now expressed in matrix form this is $M_f=\begin{pmatrix} 0.6 & -0.8 \\ 0.8 & 0.6\end{pmatrix}$

$\det(M_f)=0.6^2+0.8^2=0.36+0.64=1$ so this is an isometry (a direct rotation of center $O$).